# Using Ansible, how can I install PythonBrew system-wide?

Tags: ansible, pythonbrew

I'm trying to create a playbook with Ansible (v 1.3.3) to install Pythonbrew system-wide on a Debian server following the instructions in the [Pythonbrew readme file](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew#installation).

I am able to get Pythonbrew installed but I cannot install the specific version of Python that I want with it. I suspect the issue has to do with the shell environment Ansible is running under.

Here's my playbook script:

```
- name: Install and configure PythonBrew
  hosts: dev
  user: root
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Install PythonBrew Debian packages
      apt: pkg=${item} state=installed update-cache=yes
      with_items: ${pythonbrew_packages}

    - name: Install PythonBrew system-wide
      shell: curl -kL http://xrl.us/pythonbrewinstall | bash creates=/usr/local/pythonbrew executable=/bin/bash

    - name: Update bashrc for PythonBrew
      lineinfile:
        dest=~/.bashrc
        regexp='^'
        line='[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc'
        state=present
        create=True

    - name: Install python binary
      shell: pythonbrew install -v ${python_version} executable=/bin/bash
```

When I run this playbook, it fails with the following output

> failed: [devserver] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "pythonbrew
>   install -v 2.7.3 ", "delta": "0:00:00.016639", "end": "2013-10-11
>   15:21:40.989677", "rc": 127, "start": "2013-10-11 15:21:40.973038"}
>   stderr: /bin/bash: pythonbrew: command not found

I've been tweaking things for the last hour or so to no avail. Does anybody have any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By peeking at the [PythonBrew install script](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/blob/master/pythonbrew/installer/pythonbrewinstaller.py#L91), I was able to figure this out. (And just in time for the [deprecation of PythonBrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/commit/e8823c5494a26e2c91aa516eac80b748474ba129#diff-88b99bb28683bd5b7e3a204826ead112)!)

Here's the playbook that installs PythonBrew without manual intervention. This may be of interest to anyone trying to script PythonBrew to install automatically.

#### vars.yml

```
#
# Python/PythonBrew Settings
# TODO: replace old-style Ansible ${vars} with jinja-style {{ vars }}
#
project_name: MY_PROJECT

python:
  version: 2.7.3

pythonbrew:
  root: /usr/local/pythonbrew
  bashrc_path: $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc

  packages:
    - curl
    - zlib1g-dev
    - libsqlite3-dev
    - libssl-dev
    - libxml2
    - libxml2-dev
    - libxslt1-dev
    - libmysqlclient-dev
    - libbz2-dev
```

#### pythonbrew.yml

```
---

#
# Install and Configure PythonBrew
#
- name: Install and configure PythonBrew
  hosts: MY_HOST
  user: root
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Install PythonBrew Debian packages
      apt: pkg=${item} state=installed update-cache=yes
      with_items: ${pythonbrew.packages}

    - name: Install PythonBrew system-wide
      shell: curl -kL http://xrl.us/pythonbrewinstall | bash
        executable=/bin/bash
        creates=${pythonbrew.root}

    - name: Update bashrc for PythonBrew
      lineinfile:
        dest=/root/.bashrc
        regexp='^'
        line='[[ -s ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path} ]] && source ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path}'
        state=present
        create=True

    # This step allows install to continue without new shell. Pulled from:
    # https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/blob/master/pythonbrew/installer/pythonbrewinstaller.py#L91
    - name: Install python binary
      shell: export PYTHONBREW_ROOT=${pythonbrew.root}; source ${pythonbrew.root}/etc/bashrc; pythonbrew install ${python.version}
        executable=/bin/bash

    - name: Switch to python version
      shell: export PYTHONBREW_ROOT=${pythonbrew.root}; source ${pythonbrew.root}/etc/bashrc; pythonbrew switch ${python.version}
        executable=/bin/bash
```